# In Dark Souls 2, what does this white soapstone icon mean?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2, I recently noticed this white soapstone icon. What does it mean?

[image: White Soapstone Icon]

Comment: Did you burn an effigy?

Comment: As a matter of fact I did, but that was quite a few deaths ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That sign means that you cannot invade, be invaded, summon or be summoned. The effect is probably active because you have burnt a human effigy.

After all the flame in the comments [@Mondrianaire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/45820/mondrianaire) actually [took the time to test it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166047/in-dark-souls-2-what-does-this-white-soapstone-icon-mean/166054#comment223736_166054) and I report here his finding:

> You are correct and they are incorrect. The question was about the
>   symbol, not about why he could not invade or be invaded. **The covenant**
>   **of champions does not produce this symbol. The only way to have this**
>   **symbol is by actively burning an effigy**, which was your answer. I have
>   just tested this and here are two pictures, one while I was in the
>   covenant of champions, but had not burned an effigy, and one 10
>   seconds later after burning one.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxQ2E.jpg)

Comment: What do I do to make it go away?

Comment: Just wait, it's a temporary effect.

Comment: -1 This is wrong in the case of @brain56. Brain is experiencing the effect due to joining the Company of Champions, and not due to burning an effigy. The effect in this case is permanent and will not just wear off, so just waiting won't solve their problem. They will need to leave the covenant.

Comment: Well the question is about what that sign means, and I answered that. I then supposed it was because of the effigy since I didnt know he was in a covenant.

Comment: While in this certain case it's because of the Champion's covenant, the answer is right in explaining the symbol and one way the status can be caused so I don't think it deserves a down vote. You should just add that the status also gets caused by the covenant and only wears off after about 30 minutes when burning an effigy. Overall, Wipqozn's answer goes into more depth though, and actually answers brain's problem, so it should be accepted.

Comment: @DominicDeCoco: It's true that geeo is correct about the effect, but the incorrect information about the source and the additional advice about how to end the effect is misleading and doesn't solve the askers additional problem (evident by the comments) of how to end the effect.

Comment: +1 to cancel out the downvote. I think the answer meant well, it was just lacking in depth.

Comment: @brain56 -1 to cancel out the +1 to cancel out the -1.  This person should change the part of their answer that is wrong if they want their answer to not be considered wrong.  There's no value in keeping it the way it is - just edit it.

Comment: Voting to cancel out others' votes is not the way it should be done.  Vote on the *content*, not on how others do.  [Further reading](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system)

Comment: Guys this is beyond ridiculous. The answer is correct but you are still free to vote down, flag for moderator attention or edit the quwstion yourself if you feel like. Just stop crying in the comments because it makes no sense whatsoever and it just makes you look ridiculously stupid.

Comment: You are correct and they are incorrect. The question was about the symbol, not about why he could not invade or be invaded. The covenant of champions **does not produce this symbol**. ***The only way to have this symbol is by actively burning an effigy***, which was your answer. I have just tested this and here are two pictures, one while I was in the covenant of champions, but had not burned an effigy, and one 10 seconds later after burning one. http://imgur.com/NZ7wc10

Comment: @Mondrianaire: Interesting. In that case I have switched my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 17):

> It appears I was wrong about the company of champions producing this symbol. Please see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166047/in-dark-souls-2-what-does-this-white-soapstone-icon-mean#comment223735_166058) comment and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166054/8350) answer,

The sign means you're unable to engage in any PVP (summon others, be summoned, invade others, or be invaded). You gain this effect by burning  a [human effigy](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/human-effigy) at a bonfire. This is a temporary effect which will wear off after an [hour.](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Human+Effigy#.U156U6HkgR0) The symbol will only appear if the effect is gained via this method ([source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166047/in-dark-souls-2-what-does-this-white-soapstone-icon-mean/166058?noredirect=1#comment223735_166058)).

Comment: This answer is incorrect for the question being asked for the exact same reasons you were fighting with Geeo about his answer being incomplete. The specific question was about the **symbol**, not why he cannot play with other people. The symbol *does not show up if you are only in the covenant of champions*, it **only shows up if you burn an effigy**. Although it is true that they both produce the same effects, this answer is in fact, incorrect for the question being asked.

Comment: I have tested this myself personally.  imgur.com/NZ7wc10

Comment: @Mondrianaire Nice find, I didn't think of that before. Come to think of it now, the effect might not be entirely the same, according to the Dark Souls wikia, you can still be invaded in the Covenant of Champions, it only disables friendly summonings: http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Company_of_Champions You can also be invaded after burning an effigy, as it only decreases the likelihood of it, but it's not sure if the covenant also decreases the likelihood of getting invaded.

Comment: @Mondrianaire Interesting. In that  case I have changed my vote on the other answer, and will delete my answer once the accept has been removed.

Comment: @brain56 It appears I was incorrect, according to testing done by mondrianaire. I'd suggesting switching your accept so that I may delete my answer.